# Error using openblox diameter server in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, diameter-protocol

Bit of a specific one this..

I'm having trouble using the Openblox diameter stack when using Spring MVC, specifically the init method call on the transport stack:

```
import com.traffix.openblox.core.transport.TransportStack;

Stack stack = new TransportStack();
stack.init(configureStack());
```

I'm getting a null pointer exception on the call to init - note that the Configuration returned from configureStack() is valid and works on non-Spring MVC projects. Heres the stack trace:

```
 2776 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN com.traffix.openblox.core.fsm.StateMachine  - Idle failed to process <Initiate Transport Stack( Idle) 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.traffix.openblox.core.utils.logging.StackLogger.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.traffix.openblox.core.transport.Stack.g(Unknown Source)
    at com.traffix.openblox.core.transport.TransportStack.g(Unknown Source)
    at com.traffix.openblox.core.transport.u.N(Unknown Source)
    at com.traffix.openblox.core.transport.c$a.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.traffix.openblox.core.fsm.StateMachine.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.traffix.openblox.core.fsm.StateMachine.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.traffix.openblox.core.transport.u.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.traffix.openblox.core.transport.Stack.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.rory.services.pcrf.simulator.PcrfSimulator.initialize(PcrfSimulator.java:131)
    at com.rory.services.pcrf.simulator.PcrfSimulator.<init>(PcrfSimulator.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Comment: I'd suggest going and digging around in the `javap -c` disassembly of the StackLogger's init() method class.  I'd've had a look for you, but they've gone and run the free version through an obfuscator so I can't guess what code you're actually erroring in.  If it's not immediately obvious what the problem is no amount of disassembly reading is probably going to help; obviously you can't post it as its proprietary.

Comment: Thanks, seems my version is obfuscated too through and so can't view the class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some sort of conflict between Openblox and Tomcat. Workaround for now is by removing conf/logging.properties from the Tomcat directory.